# Stomach muscles burn after doing crunches?

Tags: weight-loss, abdominals, stomach, crunches, sit-ups

I used to be able to do 100+ crunches, but now I can only do 40 and my abs feel like they're burning so badly(after). I don't do crunches often anymore. I lost weight(about 5 pounds) before this started happening. I don't have a six pack. Why are my abs burning so bad? Help?

Comment: Probably because you stopped doing 100+ crunches. Endurance detrains relatively quickly compared to maximal strength, which would be the largest factor in being able to do 100+ crunches.

Comment: Good burn or bad burn? :)

Comment: @Kneel Before Zod Good burn but painful(not literally)

Comment: That's good then; if you're performing hundreds of crunches for abs, you're certainly doing something wrong. Abs exercises are not *(and are not meant to be)* cardio exercises. Also, I'm gonna presume that you were performing the reps faster during the 100+ range than during the 40+ ones. ***Abs exercises should be done slowly in order to activate the muscles; perform cardio exercises and watch your diet to melt the fat.***

Comment: I would also suspect a form difference. What many call crunches are hip flexions instead.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD His question is not regarding cardio or burning fat. You're not answering the question.